# Count and group by month with Linq

Tags: c#, linq

I'm pulling a list with Linq and I want to see the total numbers by month based on that list.

then I output this list to excel.

Current query and result :

```
public class CVExcelMulakatList
{
    public string CV_STATU { get; set; }
    public string GORUSMETARIHI { get; set; }
    public string YAKADURUMU { get; set; }
    public int CVCOUNT { get; set; }    
}

public ActionResult GetMulakatList(List<int> idList)
{
        MULAKATDBEntities1 db = new MULAKATDBEntities1();
        idList = idList.OrderByDescending(p => p).Take(750).ToList();
        List<string> list = new List<string>()
        {"Olumsuz", "Olumlu", "Beklemede"};
        var mulakatList= (from result in (from e in db.CV
        where list.Contains(e.CV_STATU) && idList.Contains(e.ID_CV)
        group e by new { e.CV_STATU, e.YAKADURUMU, e.GORUSME_TARİH } into gcs
        select gcs.OrderBy(x=>x.CV_STATU).FirstOrDefault()
        )
        select new CVExcelMulakatList
        {
            CV_STATU      =  result.CV_STATU,
            YAKADURUMU    =  result.YAKADURUMU,
            GORUSMETARIHI =  result.GORUSME_TARİH.ToString()
           
        }).ToList();
}
```

print out :

[image]

but I want to see the following values ​​as a result of the output I sent to excel.

[image]

So what I want to do is; grouping CV_STATU, GORUSMETARIHI and YAKADURUMU and counting values ​​from the same month.

how need I change to query ?

Comment: Recommended reading: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/266563/do-non-english-words-increase-the-probability-of-receiving-downvotes/

Comment: If we can copy-and-paste a self-contained unit test that allows us to see your problem and the expected output then we will be able to give you much better advice. Please provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly your requirements:
You want to have, for each month the total of each entry which have the same
YAKADURUMU (Person?) and CV_STATU.

For instance, in month 11 you could have the following entries:

I'll arbitrarily give values in Status+Letter for CV_STATUS Values and Mr+Letter for YAKADURUMU Values

```
03/11/2021; StatusA; MrA
05/11/2021; StatusB; MrB
07/11/2021; StatusC; MrA
08/11/2021; StatusA; MrA
12/11/2021; StatusB; MrA
13/11/2021; StatusB; MrB
18/11/2021; StatusB; MrB
21/11/2021; StatusB; MrA
25/11/2021; StatusB; MrC
```

This would be translated in:

```
11; StatusA; MrA; 2
11; StatusB; MrB; 3
11; StatusC; MrA; 1
11; StatusB; MrA; 2
11; StatusB; MrC; 1
```

It is unclear if your data can contain dates from different years. If that is the case, you have to be careful not to mix identical months from different years. Like December 2020 and December 2021.
The example below takes care of this, but the method could be different depending on your needs.

Anyway, the solution consists simply as grouping your entry by all the relevant informations: here month (and possibly year), CV_STATU and YAKADURUMU. Then count how many entries are in each group.

First, a more internationally friendly version using English for variable names:

```cs
public class CVExcelMulakatList
{
    public string Status { get; set; }
    public string Date { get; set; }
    public string Person { get; set; }
    public int CvCount { get; set; }    
}


var result = db.CV
    .Where(e => list.Contains(e.status) && idList.Contains(e.idPerson))
    .GroupBy(e => new 
        {
            Date = new
            {
                Month = e.Date.Month,
                Year = e.Date.Year
            },
            e.Person,
            e.Status
        })
    .Select(g => new CVExcelMulakatList
        {
            Date = $"{g.Key.Date.Year}-{g.Key.Date.Month}",
            Person = g.Key.Person,
            Status = g.Key.Status,
            Count = g.Count()
        })
    .ToList();
```

Which closer to your naming could be:

```cs
var mulakatList= db.CV
    .Where(e => list.Contains(e.CV_STATU) && idList.Contains(e.ID_CV))
    .GroupBy(e => new
        {
            Date = new
            {
                Month = e.GORUSMETARIHI.Month,
                Year = e.GORUSMETARIHI.Year
            },
            e.YAKADURUMU,
            e.CV_STATU
        })
    .Select(g => new CVExcelMulakatList
        {
            GORUSMETARIHI= $"{g.Key.GORUSMETARIHI.Year}-{g.Key.GORUSMETARIHI.Month}",
            YAKADURUMU= g.Key.YAKADURUMU,
            CV_STATU= g.Key.CV_STATU,
            CVCOUNT = g.Count()
        })
    .ToList();
```

Here is a Linqpad Sample so you can try:

```cs
var Statuses = new List<string>
{"StatusA", "StatusB", "StatusC", "StatusD", "StatusE" };

var Persons = new List<string>
{"MrA", "MrB", "MrC", "MrD", "MrE", "MrF"};


var rndm = new Random();

var SelectedStatuses = Statuses
    .Where(e => rndm.Next(0, 1) == 1)
    .ToList();
    
var SelectedPersons = Persons
     .Where(e => rndm.Next(0, 1) == 1)
     .ToList();


var RandomDataSet = Enumerable
    .Range(0, 10)
    .Select(e => new
    {
        index = e,
        Date = DateTime.Now.AddHours(rndm.Next(0, 480)),
        Person = Persons[rndm.Next(0,2)],
        Statut = Statuses[rndm.Next(0,2)]
    })
    .ToList()
    .Dump();
    

var result = RandomDataSet
    .Where(e => Statuses.Contains(e.Statut) && Persons.Contains(e.Person))
    .GroupBy(e => new
        {
            Date = new
            {
                Month = e.Date.Month,
                Year = e.Date.Year
            },
            e.Person,
            e.Statut
        })
    .Select(g => new
        {
            Date = $"{g.Key.Date}",
            Person = g.Key.Person,
            Status = g.Key.Statut,
            Count = g.Count()
        })
    .OrderBy(e => e.Count)
    .Dump();
```

Results for a particular run are:

```
0   01/11/2021 19:43    MrB StatusA
1   04/11/2021 10:43    MrA StatusA
2   15/11/2021 02:43    MrB StatusA
3   16/11/2021 13:43    MrB StatusA
4   12/11/2021 23:43    MrA StatusA
5   06/11/2021 00:43    MrB StatusB
6   06/11/2021 15:43    MrA StatusA
7   29/10/2021 06:43    MrA StatusA
8   02/11/2021 03:43    MrA StatusA
9   10/11/2021 19:43    MrB StatusB


{ Month = 10, Year = 2021 } MrA StatusA 1
{ Month = 11, Year = 2021 } MrB StatusB 2
{ Month = 11, Year = 2021 } MrB StatusA 3
{ Month = 11, Year = 2021 } MrA StatusA 4
```